# Receive User‘s IP Address from Browser

Tags: browser, ip

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

is it possible to receive the user‘s IP address from the browser/ via browser‘s meta data? I‘ve been searching for a solution and just found suggestions like reading the user‘s IP address via a web service.
We already have implemented a web service to read the IP address, however, there is a proxy inbetween the server and the client, thus we just get the IP address from the proxy. So we thought a possible solution could be reading the user’s IP address from the browser.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way to retrieve the actual client IP address through a proxied connection. Some proxies insert a `X-Forwarded-For` header, some do it some other way and many obscure the client's address.

You can try querying the IP address from the user's browser via JavaScript, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript).